# Preventing item break inside a multicols environment

Tags: enumerate, multicol

I have the following code, which consists of an `enumerate` environment inside a `multicol` environment.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}

\item Examples set 1.

\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Example 2.

\item Example 1

Multiple paragraphs

and another paragraph.

\item Example 3.
\item Example 4.

\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image: The code's output.]

How can one prevent the second item of the second level being broken into two columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could enclose the `\item` that you don't want to be split in two columns into a `minipage` environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}

\item Examples set 1.

\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Example 2.

\item \begin{minipage}{\linewidth} Example 1

Multiple paragraphs

and another paragraph.
\end{minipage}
\item Example 3.
\item Example 4.

\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It works, but the output may look not so nice. For instance, please add the following code to the first item of the second level: `\begin{tabular}{|c|c|} \hline 1 & 2\tabularnewline \hline 3 & 4\tabularnewline \hline \end{tabular}` (the table to be placed in the second paragraph of the respective item) and see the result.

Comment: @PaulSmith: Adding `\item[\vspace{\fill}]` as the last item will result in the following output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yhuic.png